# JavaScript: Accessing 'closed' variables in an inherited sub-module

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, inheritance, module

I've got a module object that I want to clone and then override a function for.

```
var Module1 = (function () {
 var hello = "hi there!";
  return {
   sayHello : function () {
     console.log(hello);
   }
  }
})();

 var Module2 = (function (old) {
  var my = {}, key;
   for (key in old) {
    if (old.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      my[key] = old[key];
    }
  }

  my.sayHello = function () {
    console.log(old.hello + " again");
  }

  return my;
}(Module1));
```

Is there a way to access the 'private' variable 'hello' from the submodule?  Calling `Module2.sayHello()` (on the code shown above) prints `undefined again!`.

Comment: As `su-` said you can use a public function to return the `private` variable like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fsR4x/1/). Hope this helps.

Comment: can you access a private variable from an outside scope? No; that's the point of a private variable :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

You can add

```
getHello : function () {
    return hello;
}
```

into Module1's return block, in this case you expose a public function which reuturn's Module1's private vairable hello.

Comment: +1, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fsR4x/1/) and may be you can use an example.

Comment: That's what I suspected.  The variable needed to stay private, so I altered my object design.  Thanks.